# Bootstrap datepicker set dates when creating the datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I've an issue with the [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/): I need to set dates when instantiating the datepicker, without triggering the dateChange event. The reason is that I'm listening to the datechange event to submit a form, so I can't trigger it for setting the selected dates.
I need to be able to set the two days selected from data I store in a div

```
const $picker = $('.datetimepicker2').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    multidate: 2,
    debug: true,
    format: 'dd/mm/yy',
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        if($picker && $picker.datepicker('getDates').length === 2) {
            const selectedDates = $picker.datepicker('getDates');
            const startDate = moment(selectedDates[0]);
            const endDate = moment(selectedDates[1]);
            const day = moment(date);
            if(day.isAfter(startDate) && day.isBefore(endDate)) {
                return {
                    enabled: true,
                    classes: 'active'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).on('changeDate', (event) => {
    const startDate = moment(event.dates[0]).format('DD/MM/YY');
    const $form = $('.main_search').find('form');
    const $input = $('<input>', { name: 'start_date', value: startDate , type: 'hidden'});
    $form.append($input);
    $form.submit();
});
```

The problem is that if I set dates with this code, it will submit the form

```
const homeData = $('#home-data').data();

if( homeData.startDate ) {
    let dates = [];
    dates.push(homeData.startDate);
    $picker.datepicker('setDates', dates);
}
```

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap?, Which datePicker? (there are hundreds for bootstrap) is the datepicker used compatible with that of bootstrap?

Comment: @MrJ added a link to the datepicker

Comment: this is because you have a `$form.submit();` in `.on('changeDate', (event ...`

Comment: @MrJyes, choosing a date triggers a form, that's why I wanted to be able to set the dates as the starting dates in the calendar without triggering the event

Comment: SO you have to set your dates before adding event Change on it,, or disable this event when you put your values